# Big-O of loop over dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, big-o

I'm interested in the big-O complexity of a loop over the same dictionary twice and then loop over the length of a specific key in the dictionary, as shown in the pseudocode. What is the Big-O for each loop, and what would the final Big-O be?

I have tried looking at other big-O threads in here, but they are either confusing to me, due to my restricted knowledge of big-O, or not as case specific as what I'm looking for.

Thanks

```
dictionary = A dictionary with 100 keys and corresponding values of 10-20 characters each

for Akey in dictionary:
    do something
    for Bkey in dictionary:
        do something
        for i in range(len(dictionary[Bkey]))
            do something
```

Comment: In order to get nice answers, you need to ask a question.

Comment: My apologies, I have added some questions.

Comment: in fact, your pseudo code is not clear.  Why do you want to nest the Akey and BKey loops. What is the **range**" supposed to mean ?

Comment: I want to nest them to compare all keys to the first key, and then to the next key and so forth. I am during som simple calculations in between. range(len()) will loop over the range of the length of the keys value. So if the value of the key has 20 characters, i will loop like 0..1...2. etc.

Answer (score 1):

For python dictionaries, which are based on a hash-table the worst case of finding an element is O(n). However, the amortized average case is O(1). So if you do a loop over all elements it is O(1) x n -> O(n), unless you have the degenerate case of bad hash-codes and then you have O(n^2). If you do several similar operations but the number of those operations is fixed and doesn't depend on n it doesn't change the O.

if you nest a loop in another loop you will have to multiply the cost.

O(n*const)->O(n). Now you were talking about doing something with the keys but didn't mention the values.

From the pseudocode it seems that you want to take a list of the keys. Iterating over all the keys is O(n).

Comment: Thanks!
So if I get it right. The last loop (looping over the length of a key) doesn't add to the final Big-O notation, as it is constant? In that case, would it be fair to say that the final Big-O would be O(n^2), due to looping twice over the same dictionary?

Comment: well, depends on the keys. If your key is extremely long and the size is comparable to the number of elements then it will influence the O

Comment: Say it is only about 10-20 characters long, but the dictionary will have over 100 keys.

Comment: the big O notation and algorithm complexity are intended to analyse algorithms over large N. For small numbers of N all kind of secondary factors can have larger influence(unless you have some exponential complexity where even 100 elements will render huge times). Like language chosen, compiler, etc. For hash keys, for example calculating the hash code involves scanning the whole of the key. While using the hash code might be "cheaper" than calculating it.

Comment: I see, I guess my example is too vague.