# How to find values inside of a massive JSON object faster?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, algorithm, search

I'm building a word-game in React that, previously, would send user-made words to an online dictionary API as a fetch request, in order to validate the words. However, the servers for the API have been down recently and I no longer want to rely on a third-party in order for my game to work. I had the idea previously to implement a local dictionary in hopes that it would make my game run more smoothly, thanks to cutting out the fetch wait time (however small). After implementing the local dictionary, though, I've noticed that lookup times are a bit longer.

The dictionary file is a massive JSON object (370,000+ lines) that I am importing into my main component like so: `import * as data from '../../dictionary/words_dictionary.json';`
The JSON is structured like this:

```
"afterwash": 1,
"afterwhile": 1,
"afterwisdom": 1,
"afterwise": 1,
"afterwit": 1,
"afterwitted": 1,
"afterword": 1,
"afterwork": 1,
```

In order to validate a word that a user has submitted, I am merely checking if the word exists in the keys of my JSON file, as such:

```
if (Object.keys(data).includes(orderedInput.toLowerCase())) {
  dispatch(actions)
else {
  dispatch(other actions)
}
```

I realize of course that my implementation is a horribly slow and inefficient one, however, I have little experience in search optimization. If there is an easy, better way to accomplish this, I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Can you include a sample of the JSON file contents?

Comment: @code Yes, apologies. I have edited to include a sample.

Comment: a dictionary lookup is O(1) so I'm not sure how you expect to improve time complexity of your lookup ([eg more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56149989/14343465))

Comment: using Map prototype! [Map MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: I think this is too much for the client. Perform the lookup on your own server, with a proper database that can do this fast.

Answer (score 4):

Just index the object, `includes` is a brute force search.

```js
if (data[orderedInput.toLowerCase()]) {
  dispatch(actions)
else {
  dispatch(other actions)
}
```

---

I would personally use a `Set` for this, probably no difference in lookup performance but I think slightly better on memory, no need for the 1's.

```js
export const data = new Set([
  "afterwash",
  "afterwhile",
  "afterwisdom",
  "afterwise",
  ...
]);
```

```js
if (data.has(orderedInput.toLowerCase())) {
  dispatch(actions)
else {
  dispatch(other actions)
}
```

Comment: Why would it be faster to parse a JS file than to parse a JSON file?

Comment: JSON is an extra step - it's just a big string - it must be parsed into a JS object before it can be interpreted by the browser. JSON is usually just used to send data over a network, it's better to use a JS object if it is a local file.

Comment: But JS code must also be parsed into a JS object, just changing the extension from .json to .js doesn't magically remove the need for parsing.

Comment: Good point, looking it up looks like JSON is actually faster: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-javascript-works-optimizing-for-parsing-efficiency/ removed that bit, but `Set`s aren't serializable : (

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie wow calling JSON.parse(...) on a string is faster than just declaring an object, kind of mind blowing https://v8.dev/blog/cost-of-javascript-2019#json thanks for teaching me something new

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

I wasn't aware of the optimizations JavaScript's object naturally employs, meaning it'll be much faster if you directly perform a lookup on the JavaScript object. The [benchmark](https://perf.link/#eyJpZCI6InVwNXRlYW45dXN0IiwidGl0bGUiOiJkaWN0aW9uYXJ5IHNlYXJjaCIsImJlZm9yZSI6IkFycmF5LnByb3RvdHlwZS5yYW5kb20gPSBmdW5jdGlvbigpIHtcbiAgcmV0dXJuIHRoaXNbKE1hdGgucmFuZG9tKCkgKiB0aGlzLmxlbmd0aCkgfCAwXTtcbn1cblxuY29uc3QgYWxwaGFiZXQgPSBcImFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6XCIuc3BsaXQoXCJcIik7XG5jb25zdCBmYWtlRGF0YUxpc3QgPSBBcnJheS5mcm9tKHsgbGVuZ3RoOiA1MDAwMDAgfSwgKF8sIGkpID0%2BIHtcbiAgY29uc3Qgd29yZExlbmd0aCA9ICgoTWF0aC5yYW5kb20oKSAqIDIwKSB8IDApICsgMTtcbiAgbGV0IHdvcmQgPSBcIlwiO1xuICBmb3IobGV0IGkgPSAwOyBpIDwgd29yZExlbmd0aDsgaSsrKVxuICAgIHdvcmQgKz0gYWxwaGFiZXQucmFuZG9tKCk7XG4gIHJldHVybiB3b3JkO1xufSk7XG5jb25zdCBmYWtlRGF0YSA9IGZha2VEYXRhTGlzdC5yZWR1Y2UoKGEsIGIpID0%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%3D) varies between the `in` operator and Set, but given you're already using an object, `in` would probably be optimal:

```js
if (orderedInput.toLowerCase() in data) {
  dispatch(actions)
else {
  dispatch(other actions)
}
```

tl;dr use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) or Set, which already implement advanced optimization algorithms.

---

First of all, by calling `Object.keys` you would have to re-access the entire list of words, which would add to the amount of time. If you could instead transform your JSON file to an array (arrays are valid as the root of a JSON object) it would eliminate that call. You can transform the data with a simple Node script you manually run, so you don't have to call it every time a user types:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const file = fs.readFileSync("path/to/words_dictionary.json");
fs.writeFileSync("path/to/words_dictionary.json", Object.keys(file));
```

You just have to run that once, then you can remove the object and you eliminate the entire `Object.keys` call.

---

Secondly, and perhaps more importantly, you can use the [`trie`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure to significantly optimize your time complexity.

[image: trie illustration by Booyabazooka (based on PNG image by Deco). Modifications by Superm401. - own work (based on PNG image by Deco), Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=1197221]
*trie illustration | By Booyabazooka (from wikipedia)*

Here's my sample implementation:

```js
// create a custom trie implementation
class Trie {
  constructor(data) {
    this.root = {}; // use an object to represent the tree
    this.end = Symbol("trieEnd"); // use a symbol to represent the end of a word

    // convert each letter into a key
    for(const i of data) {
      i.split("").reduce((ref, letter, index) => {
        ref[letter] = {...(ref[letter] || {})};
        if(index === i.length - 1) {
          ref[letter][this.end] = 1; // mark this is as the end of a word
        }
        return ref[letter];
      }, this.root);
    }
  }
  search(word) {
    let pos = this.root;
    
    for(let i in word) {
      pos = pos[word[i]];
      
      if(typeof pos === "undefined")
        return false;
      
      if(i == word.length - 1) {
        // test if this end is an actual end
        if(!Object.hasOwn(pos, this.end))
          return false;
      }
    }
    
    return true;
  }
}

const t = new Trie(["hello", "hell", "hi", "boy"]);
console.log(
  t.search("hello"),
  t.search("boy"),
  t.search("ho"),
  t.search("not in here"),
  t.search("h")
);
```

#### Benchmarks

Just to prove that trie is *much* faster (a half-million wordlist is generated, and 100000 random words inside the wordlist are chosen to be found):

```js
// set up
Array.prototype.random = function() {
  return this[(Math.random() * this.length) | 0];
}

const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
const fakeDataList = Array.from({ length: 500000 }, (_, i) => {
  const wordLength = ((Math.random() * 20) | 0) + 1;
  let word = "";
  for(let i = 0; i < wordLength; i++)
    word += alphabet.random();
  return word;
});

class Trie {
  constructor(data) {
    this.root = {};
    this.end = Symbol("trieEnd");
    for(const i of data) {
      i.split("").reduce((ref, letter, index) => {
        ref[letter] = {...(ref[letter] || {})};
        if(index === i.length - 1) {
          ref[letter][this.end] = 1;
        }
        return ref[letter];
      }, this.root);
    }
  }
  search(word) {
    let pos = this.root;
    
    for(let i in word) {
      pos = pos[word[i]];
      
      if(typeof pos === "undefined")
        return false;
      
      if(i == word.length - 1) {
        if(!Object.hasOwn(pos, this.end))
          return false;
      }
    }
    
    return true;
  }
}

function trieSearch(word, trie) {
  return trie.search(word);
}
function naiveSearch(word, list) {
  return list.includes(word);
}

const findList = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
  findList.push(fakeDataList.random());
function runManyTimes(fn, data) {
  for(const w of findList) {
    fn(w, data);
  }
}

console.time("naive search");
runManyTimes(naiveSearch, fakeDataList);
console.timeEnd("naive search");

console.time("trie initialization");
const t = new Trie(fakeDataList);
console.timeEnd("trie initialization");

console.time("trie search");
runManyTimes(trieSearch, t);
console.timeEnd("trie search");
```

Sure, the initialization takes a while (keep in mind the trie only needs to be initialized once on page load, not on each search), but after that each search is about 16x faster. Quite an improvement to me.

*For me, the naive search took ~8s, trie initialization took ~4s, and trie search took ~0.5s.*

Comment: This seems like an incredibly complicated way to do it, given that you can simply use a regular object or a Set, which does all that for you behind the hood. No need for reinventing the wheel when all the tools needed are already available in plain Javascript.

Comment: Not a downvoter, yet... there are many uses of a Trie, but for plain lookups, this is significantly slower than the plain object or Set versions.  I added them to yours and got: *naive*:  `62894`ms, *trie*: `550`ms, *Set*: `463`ms, *Object*: `243`ms.

Comment: This runs a variant it in a benchmark suite: https://jsbench.me/ozlb10pvcj/1